# exec: "gcc": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-container-registry

I'm having an issue where an App Engine project will no longer build remotely (via `gcloud app deploy`)

This has started out of the blue, with no code changes at this end.  Not sure if relevant, but it's a go 1.9 project deploying to the App Engine Flex environment.

I'm not sure how to test this in the same environment as the build, since the error is coming from Google's Container Registry

Here is the log from the Container Registry console

```
starting build "73f85b4d-7370-41bd-bbb2-bcf42fc38873" 

FETCHSOURCE 
Fetching storage object: gs://staging.[project].appspot.com/us.gcr.io/[project]/appengine/default.1ed3c690ead06f27aa651a30fab342611:latest#1531698266413753 
Copying gs://staging.[project].appspot.com/us.gcr.io/[project]/appengine/default.1ed3c690ead49f731806f27aa630fab342611:latest#1531698266413753... 
Operation completed over 1 objects/1.7 MiB.  

BUILD 
Starting Step #0 
Step #0: Pulling image: gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/go1-builder@sha256:c62ac3fbec31ddec70601d6c5b44d07063bcff6a823bdcf5e0bbaa9d3799d1db 
Step #0: sha256:c62ac3fbec31ddec70601d6c5b44d07063bcff6a823bdcf5e0bbaa9d3799d1db: Pulling from gcp-runtimes/go1-builder 
Step #0: Digest: sha256:c62ac3fbec31ddec70601d6c5b44d07063bcff6a823bdcf5e0bbaa9d3799d1db 
Step #0: Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/go1-builder@sha256:c62ac3fbec31ddec70601d6c5b44d07063bcff6a823bdcf5e0bbaa9d3799d1db 
Step #0: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in $PATH Finished 
Step #0 ERROR ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/go1-builder@sha256:c62ac3fbec31ddec70601d6c5b44d07063bcff6a823bdcf5e0bbaa9d3799d1db" failed: exit status 2
```

Comment: Can you check your PATH value in your ~/.bashrc? Does it include /usr/bin?

Comment: In my ~/.bashrc or the remote one? I don't know how to access the running instance in GCR...

Comment: The remote one.

Comment: Is it possible to access the remote shell in GCR? I guess that's is really my question, if I could get in and have a look I might be able to fix it.

Comment: Maybe using cloud shell? https://console.cloud.google.com/getting-started?cloudshell

Comment: I've had a look through the docs and I can't see any specific references to it. Do you know if it's possible to test with the `gcr.io` images locally?  Even if I manage that, and I fix the `PATH`, I don't see a way to modify Google's container templates.

Comment: Not sure: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/container-structure-test/issues/93 maybe?

Comment: You can run a build with a build step that overrides the entrypoint to use the bash shell and echo your $PATH -- set the `entrypoint` on `BuildStep` to `/bin/bash` and use args `[ "-c", "whatever bash command you want to run" ]`.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using container [gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/go1-builder](http://gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/go1-builder) as your build step. Looking at the [source in GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-docker/tree/master/runtime-builder), I see that there have been no updates since ~late June. I see in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-docker/blob/master/runtime-builder/Dockerfile) that the base image in the `FROM` directive is `gcr.io/google-appengine/debian9:latest`, and a look at that image reveals no `gcc` installed. I see no step in the `Dockerfile` installing gcc, and looking at your build step image confirms that it isn't there:

```
~$ docker run --rm -t -i --entrypoint /bin/bash gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/go1-builder@sha256:c62ac3fbec31ddec70601d6c5b44d07063bcff6a823bdcf5e0bbaa9d3799d1db -- which gcc
Unable to find image 'gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/go1-builder@sha256:c62ac3fbec31ddec70601d6c5b44d07063bcff6a823bdcf5e0bbaa9d3799d1db' locally
sha256:c62ac3fbec31ddec70601d6c5b44d07063bcff6a823bdcf5e0bbaa9d3799d1db: Pulling from gcp-runtimes/go1-builder
e154cec6816f: Pull complete 
<pulls elided>
Digest: sha256:c62ac3fbec31ddec70601d6c5b44d07063bcff6a823bdcf5e0bbaa9d3799d1db
Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/go1-builder@sha256:c62ac3fbec31ddec70601d6c5b44d07063bcff6a823bdcf5e0bbaa9d3799d1db
~$
```

Perhaps an earlier version of the base `debian9` image had it installed, you could dig into history to look. But it looks like there is no recent change to the `go1-builder` image to remove gcc.

If you need `gcc`, you can always separate building your app from deploying it. Build with your own `cloudbuild.yaml` via `gcloud container builds submit` and then deploy the built container using `gcloud app deploy --image-url=...` With full control over the build, you can always based on the `go-builder` image and install additional tooling you need like `gcc` on top of that before using Docker to build your final app container.

Comment: I guess this is my best bet. It does seem strange that that Google's build image can't even build the App Engine SDK! (when I remove it as a dep, it deploys fine)

Comment: I filed this issue: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-docker/issues/141; if this is critical to you, they no doubt accept pull requests...

Comment: Another option is to change the `app.yaml` to have `runtime: custom` and create your own Dockerfile with your favorite image to build the app:
```
FROM golang:latest
RUN mkdir /app
ADD . /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN go build -o main .
CMD ["/app/main"]
```

Comment: Got here after failing to deploy the "Hello World!" example in the tutorial on Google Cloud Platform. Turns out I need to build with my own cloudbuild.yaml, or create my own Dockerfile and image, or discover where the dependencies on gcc are. Welcome to Entry Level.